# Registering process unhandledRejection listener doesn't work in AWS lambda

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda

I'm using a package that sometimes returns unhandled rejections. I'm using the following inside my lambda handler to be able to catch these rejections.

```
    process.on('unhandledRejection', (error) => {
      logger.error('Unhandled Rejection at:', { error });
    });
```

The problem is that the above listener never runs. And it seems like AWS has its own event listener registered or some similar scenario.
Any Idea?

P.S I'm using middyjs.

Answer (score 0):

After days of trying different solutions and researching I found a way through it.
If I remove the AWS listener at the beginning of the lambda execution and register my own unhandled rejection listener as follows, then it'll work.

```
process.removeAllListeners('unhandledRejection');
process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, promise) => {
// ....
});
```